# Bash is removing newline

Tags: bash

When I am doing this:

```
 echo -e "test1 test2 test3\ntest1 test2 test3" | awk '{print($2)}'
```

I get the printout:

```
test2
test2
```

but when I do like this:

```
test=`echo -e "test1 test2 test3\ntest1 test2 test3" | awk '{print($2)}'`
echo $test
```

I get the printout:

```
test2 test2
```

I want the result as a column as in the first example but also want it in a variable.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try quotes here:

```
echo "$test"
```

should help.